# Related to Maclaurin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, intuition

Can you guys tell me how to proof Maclaurin's theorem with Young's form of Remainder?

Apology: My book only contains the Lagrange's and Cauchy's Form of Remainder.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you state what these forms are.  For one thing, not everybody remembers all their formulas by name. And you will get a better response if you show what you have tried.  If you have some partial progress to show, then it may be much easier to answer you.

Comment: i just need the value of n which i put in $R_n$ that's all i dont need the whole proof